# SnackBar duration parameter not defined

Tags: flutter

I want to change the duration of the SnackBar from the default of 4s to 1s. This is how I think I should do it base:

```
SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(
    content: Text("Test complete.",
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 1)
));
```

But I get a compilation error saying

> The named parameter 'duration' is not defined.

Comment: Nevermind, it was a syntax error.

Comment: hehe.. It happens.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error is

```
content: Text("Test complete.",
```

should be

```
content: Text("Test complete."),
```

I would have deleted the question but I guess too much time had gone by.